# Jquery draggable using localstorage not working after page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

So I have set up Jquery draggable so a user can change the positions of divs within a parent div.

When the first drop is performed, all the positions are saved to localstorage. This data is then updated each time a drop is conducted.

When the page is refreshed, the div positions are all displayed correctly based on the saved positions in the localstorage. When I then click a div to begin the drag and drop procedure, the surrounding divs do not move as expected or how they did prior to the page refresh.

HTML

```
    <div id="sortable">
<div id="test0" style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
    <div class='ui-state-default'>Test0</div>
</div>
<div id="test1" style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
    <div class='ui-state-default'>Test1</div>
</div>
<div id="test2" style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
    <div class='ui-state-default'>Test2</div>
</div>
<div id="test3" style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
    <div class='ui-state-default'>Test3</div>
</div>
<div id="test4" style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
    <div class='ui-state-default'>Test4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="localStorage.clear();">Clear Local Storage</button>
```

Javascript

```
    $( function() {

    newPosVal = [];

    if (localStorage.getItem("newData") != null){

        var storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newData"));

        console.log("New position Local Storage data being used:");
        console.log(storedData);

                    for (var i = 0; i < storedData.length; i++) {
                        console.log("stored: #test" + storedData[i]['div_id'] + " " + storedData[i]['offset_top_position']);
                        var id = storedData[i]['div_id'];
                        var position = storedData[i]['offset_top_position'];
                        $('#test' + id).offset({top:position});

                        console.log("Pos Check: #test" + id, $("#test" + id).offset().top);
                    }

    }

    $( '#sortable' ).sortable({
        revert: false,
        stop: function() {

            if (localStorage.getItem("newData") != null){

                var dataNew = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("newData"));

                console.log("New position Local Storage data being used:");
                console.log(dataNew);

                    for (var i = 0; i < dataNew.length; i++) {
                        console.log("previous: #test" + dataNew[i]['div_id'] + " " + dataNew[i]['offset_top_position']);
                        id = dataNew[i]['div_id'];
                        position = dataNew[i]['offset_top_position'];
                        offset = $('#test' + id).offset();
                        newPosVal[i] = {"div_id":id, "offset_top_position":offset.top};
                        console.log("Newly stored: #test" + id, $("#test" + id).offset().top);
                    }

                console.log("New Position Using Local Storage data: " + JSON.stringify(newPosVal));
                localStorage.setItem("newData", JSON.stringify(newPosVal));

            } else {

                console.log("No div position data is being used");

                    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
                        var id = i;
                        var offset = $('#test' + id).offset();
                        newPosVal[i] = {"div_id":id, "offset_top_position":offset.top};
                    }

                console.log("First Position Data: " + JSON.stringify(newPosVal));
                localStorage.setItem("newData", JSON.stringify(newPosVal));

            }

        }
    });

    $( '#draggable' ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        //helper: 'clone',
        revert: false
    });

});
```

Comment: Did your problem is solved. If solved please update